# node REPL .exit within debugger on Windows

Tags: node.js, debugging, exit, read-eval-print-loop

I don't suppose this would be something that actually works, right? That would be silly. I remember it working on Mac, I imagine it works on other nixes, but apparently on Windows repl from within node debug does not respect .exit the same way. On Mac it would drop back into debugger, allowing you to continue the execution. On Windows, it appears to halt the entire app.

Anyone know of a way around this? I'm running node 0.10.26.

For now I've switched to using node-debug for in-browser debug control. I do wish terminal control worked though!

Thanks!

Comment: `.exit` should, afaik, exit the app. Try Ctrl-C to exit the repl and return to the debugger.

Comment: yeah, already tried that. Like I say I know it worked on Mac last I used it. This is on Windows 7 running the bin from the download link on the node site.

Comment: It's working for me on XP, 7, 8, Ubuntu 10.04-13.10, and Amazon Linux all on 0.10.26. I don't know what to tell you :(

Comment: Glad it's working for @distilledchaos. To provide something else useful on this myself if someone else is reading, I've since come to realize that **some Windows terminals have better/poorer support for Unix-ness**. What I mean by this is that some (e.g. mintty) support Ctrl-C, case sensitive filenames, etc, and some (e.g. Console or "Console2") don't.